# How can I use .split to split a string AFTER a certain word?

Tags: java

As the title says.

Let's say we have a string called "value"

```
String value = ("I need to go to the bathroom.");
```

I want value.split do such a job that it splits the string in half AFTER a certain word.

So that we have an array of strings that has 2 strings inside.

Such as

```
String[] valuearray = value.split(-whatevercodegoeshere-);
```

So we get:

valuearray 1 = I need to

valuearray 2 = go to the bathroom.

Is this possible? If not with current functions, is it possible by writing a function specifically designed for this task?

Comment: Check out regular expressions look aheads and look behinds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using a lookbeind

```
value.split("(?<=go) ")
```

This reads, split where space is preceded by go.

Lookaheads and Lookbehinds don't consume anything, only check if it's there, so go will still be in the String[] returned from split()

Comment: I added the missing equals sign.  As written, your solution didn't work.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. Good catch.